# Java "POST" retornando "Server returned HTTP response code: 411"

Tags: java, api, rest, post

As sugestões que encontrei aqui não foram suficientes para corrigir meu problema. Por isso estou abrindo o tópico.

Segue o código:

```
        URL url = new URL("https://api.onvio.com.br/dominio/integration/v1/activation/enable");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // Adicionando cabeçalhos
        con.setRequestProperty("x-integration-key", xIntegrationKey);
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + authorization);
            
        // Enviando requisição e lendo a resposta
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        
        con.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine= in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        
        Integration integrationKey = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), Integration.class);

        return integrationKey.integrationKey;
```

E o erro que esta retornando:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 411 for URL: https://api.onvio.com.br/dominio/integration/v1/activation/enable
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1964)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1959)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1958)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1528)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
    at testes.AutenticacaoAPI.GetKeyIntegrationApi(AutenticacaoAPI.java:95)
    at testes.AutenticacaoAPI.main(AutenticacaoAPI.java:26)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 411 for URL: https://api.onvio.com.br/dominio/integration/v1/activation/enable
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1914)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
    at testes.AutenticacaoAPI.GetKeyIntegrationApi(AutenticacaoAPI.java:93)
    ... 1 more
```

Tentei definir o tamanho `con.setRequestProperty("Content-Lenght", "0")` porém também não funciona.

Answer (score -2):

Depois de muitas tentativas, consegui arrumar...
Criei este método em uma nova classe, exclusiva para ele e deixei desta forma:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://api.onvio.com.br/dominio/integration/v1/activation/enable");
        
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("x-integration-key", "XXX");
        httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "YYY");
        
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("{}")); 

        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost)) {
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                String responseBody = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                IntegrationKey integrationKey = new Gson().fromJson(responseBody, IntegrationKey.class);
                System.out.println(responseBody);
                System.out.println(integrationKey.integrationKey);
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERRO");
                // handle error
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).